# Configuration of plugins

Tags: adobe, analytics

I try to use the following plugins in local mode:

```
s.Util.cookieRead https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/util_cookieread.html
s.Util.cookieWrite https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/util_cookiewrite.html
```

When I type in console i.e. s.Util.getQueryParam I take back the function which seems that the configuration in file it is allright.

```
s.Util.getQueryParam
AppMeasurement.a.Util.getQueryParam(c, b, d)
```

How ever when I go to add the example in plugin function

```
s.campaign = s.Util.getQueryParam("cid");
```

when I run my site I can't see anything of this plugin

Also when I use the

```
getNewRepeat https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/getNewRepeat.html
plugin it always shows me as New visitor.
```

Is there any special configuration I should make in order to make them to work properly?

Comment: `s.Util.getQueryParam` is a function that returns the value of a specified query string parameter. So if the url of the page the code is on is  `http://www.example.com/?cid=123` then it will return `123`

Comment: `getNewRepeat` is likely not working properly because your local environment. I assume by "local mode" you are running it on your own computer, so the page doesn't have an actual domain. This usually always causes problems with cookies and cookie based code since cookies are domain based. Update your vhost file (or equivalent) to point to some random domain for your localhost so you can go to your pages with a properly structured url instead of file.. or localhost..

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstand what `cookieWrite` does.  or perhaps also how cookies work in general?  That method writes a cookie.  It's not supposed to return the value you wrote to the cookie. You already know what value you are writing to the cookie so why would the *write* function return that?  The idea is that you write something to a cookie and then later on retrieve it with a read method.  So you'd use the *read* method when assigning to your variable

Comment: sure,  can you please explain what you are trying to do as far as tracking?  What is your goal here,  what are you trying to track

Comment: okay.. see my posted answer.. it's nothing more than what's already shown in the docs, so it makes me wonder if there's more to what you need than that, but okay..

Comment: `getQueryParam` will get the value of a url param if it exists. It cannot set url params, there are no methods for that

Comment: It is possible to use Javascript to add a url param to the url though..why? Make a new question explaining what you want to achieve and why, because generally, url params are not set clientside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// set a session cookie named foo to value 'bar'
s.Util.cookieWrite('foo','bar');

// look for cookie named 'foo' and return value if found, and assign it to prop1
s.prop1 = s.Util.cookieRead('foo');
```